# What is this mystery css that lighthouse is flagging up?

Tags: css, audit, lighthouse

I'm using Chrome's Lighthouse audit to make some performance improvements to a website and there are some styles under the "Remove unused CSS' section that I cannot locate anywhere on the site.

The ones I am questioning are the 2 lines starting html, body etc.

They look a bit like reset styles but aren't the ones I have in the CSS file.

I've tried searching the theme files (this is a shopify site), the page source, turning off javascript and these styles don't show up anywhere.
Has anyone encountered this before?

[image]

Comment: The source address (cdn.shopify.com) indicates that they're probably url imports or something similar, try looking around for that. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a Shopify Site it's using the Shopify style CDN by default. Since it's a CDN the css files are not going to be found in your project directory but rather on Shopify's website. An example of a style CDN can be found [here](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/), this one is for bootstrap.It uses a URL to access style options that are stored on their servers so you don't have to download the CSS locally.

[Here's more on CDNs](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/).

As for your issue, it looks like your project is referencing these CDNs but you're not using them. If you can find where in your project these CDNs are linked and remove them/comment them out it should resolve the issue.

[Here's a similar question](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Discussion/Defer-unused-CSS/td-p/476124) about whether or not it's safe to remove unused/deferred styles for Shopify.